# How do I make a copy of java.util.Properties object?

Tags: java, collections, properties, copy, copy-constructor

I have the following field and constructor:

```
private final Properties properties;

public PropertiesExpander(Properties properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
}
```

The good practice is to make copy of every mutable collection in constructor. I want to make a shallow, independent copy. How can I achieve that?

My first idea was to use `putAll()` method:

```
private final Properties properties = new Properties();

public PropertiesExpander(Properties properties) {
    this.properties.putAll(properties);
}
```

Is there any simpler, more performant or more idiomatic way of doing that? Maybe there are some utils for that in Guava or Apache Commons?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using `putAll()` is great... if you need to stay with `Properties`. It runs in `O(number of elements)` and has very little overhead. The only difference I would recommend is to stay away from `Properties` for performance reasons unless you need it, because it inherits from [`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html). Also, don't use `Properties` because it doesn't actually conform to any interface, just `Dictionary` which is an abstract class; this will limit your options. See: [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1768232)

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the `Map` interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, `Hashtable` is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) in place of `Hashtable`. If a thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is recommended to use [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) in place of Hashtable.

**Whatever you do, do not use `clone()`,** it is not secure and not performant. See: [Java: Why shouldn't clone() be used for defensive copying?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29528850/1768232)

---

You edited your question to ask about Guava and apache-commons. If it's purely a defensive copy, **and it's immutable**, I would recommend using [`Map<String, String> map = ImmutableMap.copyOf(properties)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html). Note: again, this doesn't use an actual `Properties` object because `Hashtable` is not recommended unless you need it. From [the wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained)

> When you don't expect to modify a collection, or expect a collection to remain constant, it's a good practice to defensively copy it into an immutable collection.
>
> Important: Each of the Guava immutable collection implementations rejects null values. We did an exhaustive study on Google's internal code base that indicated that null elements were allowed in collections about 5% of the time, and the other 95% of cases were best served by failing fast on nulls. If you need to use null values, consider using Collections.unmodifiableList and its friends on a collection implementation that permits null. More detailed suggestions can be found here.

Comment: `this.properties = ImmutableMap.copyOf(properties);` - this unfortunately doesn't compile

Comment: @MichalKordas `this.properties = ImmutableMap.copyOf(properties);` - it compiles with Guava 27

Answer (score 4):

Properties implements Cloneable, so it looks like you could do the following if you wanted.

```
this.properties = (Properties) properties.clone();
```

add this to your class

```
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return super.clone();
}
```

Or if you're worried about using clone, your class also implements serializable, so you could do this.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils;

this.properties = SerializationUtils.clone(properties);
```

[Properies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

[Cloneable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Properties newProps = new Properties();
properties.forEach((key, value) -> {
    newProps.setProperty((String) key, (String) value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just do it the "long" way:

```
    Iterator i = properties.keySet().iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        this.properties.put(i.next(), properties.get(i));
    }
```

Iterator is from the same java.util package as Properties, so no outside dependencies.

If the compiler warning about unchecked types bothers you, you can simply change it to (assuming your property keys are strings):

```
    Iterator<Object> i = properties.keySet().iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        this.properties.put(i.next().toString(), properties.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be simply to

```
Properties newVersion = new Properties(originalVersion);
```

It will *behave* initially as a copy of the `originalVersion`, except when the key in the `newVersion` would be deleted, it would revert back to the value as stored in the `originalVersion`. In effect, the `originalVersion` behaves as a default key/value set.

Answer (score 0):

The below program copies the one property file to another and will remove the duplicates also. The source property file may have duplicate properties but it will create the new file without any duplicate properties.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;

public class App2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream("config.properties")) {

            Properties prop = new Properties();

            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);

            writeToNewProperties(prop);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void writeToNewProperties(Properties prop) {
        Properties outPutProp = new Properties();
        // get the property value and print it out
        Set<String> stringPropertyNames = prop.stringPropertyNames();
        for (String propertyName : stringPropertyNames) {
            outPutProp.put(propertyName, prop.get(propertyName));
        }

        try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("out-config.properties")) {
            // save properties to project root folder
            outPutProp.store(output, null);
            System.out.println(outPutProp);
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```